# Google Rich Snippets: automatically detected author name on webpage: not found

Tags: google, rich-snippets

I am having trouble with Google Rich Snippets, on the verification authorship, I am getting this error:

> Email verification has not established authorship for this webpage.
>
> Email address on the mrnepal.com domain has been verified on this profile: Yes Public contributor-to link from Google+ profile to mrnepal.com: Yes
>
> **Automatically detected author name on webpage: Not Found.**

How to fix this error?

Comment: What is your email address? something@mrnepal.com? Does the email have to be something@blog.mrnepal.com?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly follow these steps to get it worked fine: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-authorship/

Checkout this image of source code:

I think, you might have added this code from word (copy paste) so " will not fetch properly in HTML. Just edit it and url reference will start pointing your google profile.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helpful. I have already done all the needed steps.

Comment: Have you tested your page in Google rich snippet testing tool?

Comment: The details in my question is from that tool.

Comment: You may have not done it correctly, i did view source of your url menepal and could not find author tag mentioned below:  <a href="https(://)plus.google.com/109412257237874861202?
   rel=author">Google</a> here you need to replace url with your profile url.

Comment: The URL I am trying to do is on http://blog.mrnepal.com

Comment: I think i got the issue, when i tried to check your author url by viewing source it seems that the " " are not properly placed. Try to click that link, it will point to wrong url.
Kindly fix it and see !! it may work.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: PeggyP meant (I think) that in the author box the link target URL contains a quotation mark that doesn't belong there. It's the  **Follow me on Google+** link.

Comment: I have just added image showing wrong reference URL in source code due to wrong placement of " ".

Comment: That is my recent attempt by using a plugin called author box. It was not working before too.

Comment: You should check syntax..kindly edit " as suggested and check. I should work !!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. It's really fiddly. I had several errors I needed to fix.

1. My first problem was that my posts were not showing up as "Mat Ellis" (my Google Profile name) but as my Wordpress user ID "matellis". I had to change my "Full Name" to match my Google Profile settings. [See the screencap](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/174e14e9-4be1-4249-a9b0-36e525960ce2/94c8f89e87c9977976568024b0c3da01).
2. My second problem was that I was confusing [Publisher-ship and Authorship](http://www.buuteeq.com/blog/googles-authorship-markup-author-vs-publisher/), and so I was using a Google Page as my link instead of my profile. You can see the difference between [my page](https://plus.google.com/100479503052673050169) and [my profile](https://plus.google.com/113473027594498160821).
3. The next thing was an error in the Google docs. It doesn't explain you have to add `?rel=author` to your Profile link. I also added this to the `a` tag. So my link went from:

   ```
   <a href="//plus.google.com/113473027594498160821?psrc=3">
   ```

   to:

   ```
   <a href="//plus.google.com/113473027594498160821?rel=author" rel="author">
   ```

   Doing these three things got my structured data test to work fine, [see this example](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?user_profile=https://plus.google.com/113473027594498160821&url=http://matellis.com/2013/01/21/life-without-apple/).

The whole process was time consuming and frustrating, made worse by Wordpress.com seeming complete lack of interest in any up-to-date SEO tools. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is a different community Mat, the reputation you have there will not work here. I have over 30000 points there but it does not give me authority to use my privileges here.

Comment: Was my answer any help?

Comment: Very helpful information, But I was already aware of these.

Answer (score 1):

Now your byline goes like this:

> Written by Nabin Nepal

Change it to this:

> Written by Nabin Nepal (Starx)

This way the name corresponds to the name on your Google+ profile.

See this: https://plus.google.com/authorship

> Make sure your byline name matches the name on your Google+ profile.

Comment: Same problem. Check [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?user_profile=https%3A%2F%2Fplus.google.com%2F100940214614580829424&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.mrnepal.com). I had tried this earlier too.

Comment: Starx is my nickname, not by original name. Google give priority to original name, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

PeggyP is right. There exist two quote symbols, and some word-processing apps use to mess them up. The equivalent for " (and right one) is " (see two perfectly vertical comas). But you've misspelled it in your metatag and you've used the other one (the wrong one), which looks like an italique " (two oblique comas). Have a care look to the quote symbol in your link rel author metatag as shown in PeggyP picture. I've also made this error tons of times.
You can compare the quotes in your other metatags, as they are correct. It's only wrong in your rel=author metatag line.

Your current line (wrong):

link rel=”author” href=”https://plus.google.com/100940214614580829424/posts”

The one you should have:

link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/100940214614580829424/posts"

Comment: That is my recent attempt by using a plugin called author box. It was not working before too.

Comment: Does the plugin use those kind of quotes? May it be you the one when using the plugin?

Comment: What if I remove that line? I think there is an option to do that.

Comment: It may be a good idea to try it (removing it). You've got it duplicated 9 lines later (at Yoast plugin) with the root url (not the /posts one)

Comment: The current link in your author metatag points me to a 404: http://blog.mrnepal.com/%E2%80%9Dhttps:/plus.google.com/100940214614580829424/posts%E2%80%9D --> No problem on removing it. I've also read [in google forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/kflbDMj5Fso/znLzkFiS7ucJ) and [in google support](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986) about the "written by" fixing it, which you have (though mixed in code with some html elements). Have you tried pointing your profile to your "About" page? (currently it points to your blog home page)

Comment: Yes I have tried that too.